# Can we use Annotations in protractor to perform e2e testing?

Tags: testing, automation, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing

In selenium, we are using some annotations like @BeforeClass @AfterClass etc.
Is there any type of annotations which we can use in Protractor.

Answer (score 1):

Jasmine already provides the global beforeEach, afterEach, beforeAll, and afterAll functions .

So, one can already use those and decide which specs to run from protractor config. As far as I understand , Jasmine does not support annotations.

One can exclude a test using `xit()` and an entire describe block using `xdescribe()`.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Let me know if that answers your question ?